# Reusing content from front page on sub page

Tags: wp-query, frontpage

I am trying to reuse content from my static front page in a different page template. But because my front page is static, I can not call it by page name. Is it possible to call the front page another way? Preferably not by ID!
My code:

```
    <?php $my_query = new WP_Query('pagename=front');
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;?>           
    /* The content I want from the front page content */
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: If you're using a Page - a static front page - call it by post ID rather than by pagename.

Comment: @WebElaine - thanks - yea ID works, but I would like to call it some other way, because it is a staging site - so when I change it to a live site on a different server the ID might change.

Comment: The answer here may help you - use the slug ('front') and 'post_type' 'page'. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979837/wordpress-query-single-post-by-slug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`get_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) you can get the page that is assigned to the front page:

```
$frontpage = get_post(get_option('page_on_front'));
```

Or as you [have it](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters):

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'page_id' => get_option('page_on_front') ) );
```